# Sending curl request for multipart/form-data

Tags: java, curl, jax-rs, multipartform-data

Is file extension necessary while sending curl request for multipart/form-data?
I had removed the extension of my two files(certificate and key) in my pc and tried to send curl request without giving any extension. It said

> curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application

My certificate and key file without extension are : **clientnoext and clientkeynoext**

Following is the curl request for above mentioned issue:

```
curl -k --location --request POST 'https://1.23.4.5/api/v/Feature/abc' --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'replace_existing: true' --header 'Authorization: Bearer ey2ebGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.JFhblwtfrV96Zs3dYgP9ei18TsVFuhPjwrxICyDEvsSq' --form 'key=@"/Users/gagan/Downloads/clientkeynoext"' --form 'certificate=@"/Users/gagan/Downloads/clientnoext"'
```

> curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application

I tried sending curl request without giving any extension for both the files but the request didnot  hit my controller and instead it threw error in commandline itself saying **curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application**

Comment: (0) this is not programming or development but (1) yes you can use filenames without 'extensions' for _any_ mediatype (2) and you don't need to specify multipart/form-data when using --form because it's the default. (3) you did something else wrong, but we don't know what. You can't be using Windows 'native' (CMD) or pwsh because this syntax wouldn't work; _IF_ you are using WSL or git4win-bash (mingw64) you can't use 'native' filenames like /Users as-is, you must convert them.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 above command works if i rename the same file and give extension. The only issue is it's not working if i remove the extension of that file.